# Help integrate $\frac{1}{x^3+x^8}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could you help me to integrate

$$
\int{\frac{dx}{x^3+x^8}}
$$

I've tried partial fraction decomposition but got $(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$ as the last term when factored the denominator.

Thank you.

Comment: $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ has complex roots equal to the primitive $10$th roots of unity. You might be able to do partial fractions with that. It will be ugly, however.

Comment: I mean, you could break out the quartic formula to factor it, but yeah....ouch.   Why do you want this one?

Comment: I thought I can make the last term the square of quadratic polynomial, but I can't.

Comment: You can factor $x^4-x^3=x^2-x+1=(x^2-2\cos(\pi/5)x +1)(x^2-2\cos(3\pi/5)x+1)$. That lets you get the two $\tan^{-1}$ terms in the Wolfram Alpha answer that C.T. got.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try!

Comment: I want this one cause my friend got it as a task and asked me to help him.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get the answer given by Wolfram Alpha is to write:

$$\frac{1}{x^3+x^8} = \frac{1}{x^3} -\frac{x^2}{x^5+1}$$

Then solve:

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^5}=\frac{a}{x+1} + \frac{bx+c}{x^2-2\cos(\pi/5)x+1}+\frac{dx+e}{x^2-2\cos(3\pi/5)x+1}$$

Since $\sin\pi/5$ and $\cos\pi/5$ are in terms of $\sqrt{5}$, you can rewrite the answer in terms of $\sin(\pi/5),\cos(\pi/5),\sin(3\pi/5),\cos(3\pi/5)$.

It still won't be pretty.

Comment: Wow, what is this factoring trick?  I've never seen such a thing before.

Comment: Which factoring trick? The roots of $x^5+1$ are $-1$ and the primitive $10$th roots of unity, which can be written as $\cos(\pi/5)\pm i\sin(\pi/5)$ and $\cos(3\pi/5)\pm i(\sin(3\pi/5)$.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer computed by Wolfram alpha below.
I wouldn't try to do this one by hand though.

[image]

Comment: I've tried already and the answer frightened me.